# How to specify yt:accessControl parameters in googleapi url request

Tags: html, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a URL like this which I use in my web application to fetch the latest videos from specific YouTube Channels:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=my_project_key&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50&format=5&channelId=channel_id

I want to add more filters to my api query and would like to add "[yt:accessControl](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html)" parameters to my query. An example would be to add the following which are in youtube api code format:

```
<yt:accesscontrol action='embed' permission='allowed' />
```

I am wondering how I can specify these filters/parameters in my URL. Looks like "action" and "permissions" belong to "accesscontrol" class of youtube apis and just using "action" and "permission" in URL might not work.

Answer (score 0):

The search endpoint can take a `videoEmbeddable` parameter, which, if set to true, indicates that only videos that are allowed to be embedded should be returned. So your example would look like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=my_project_key&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50&videoEmbeddable=true&channelId=channel_id
```

(also note that I've removed the 'format=5' parameter from your search call, as it doesn't do anything in v3 of the API ... it was an old v2 parameter that was never ported)